# fscanf() only can accept one string when read struct on file, not with int C

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I have another Problem, `fscanf()` only can read one string even, there is 2 in file, so it just repeat it.
Ex. In file

```
Name
ID
```

when I read it.

```
struct customer {
    int id;
    char name[100];
};
struct customer custid[100];

int num_cust = 1;
   strcpy(custid[num_cust].name, "Name");
   num_cust++;
   strcpy(custid[num_cust].name, "ID");
```

When writing:

```
 int i;
   for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        fprintf(test, "%s\n", custid[i].name);
   }
```

And reading:

```
for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        rewind(test);
        fscanf(test, "%s\n", custid[i].name);
        printf("%s\n", custid[i].name);
    }
```

The Result:

```
Name
Name

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.007 s
Press any key to continue.
```

But When I do it with int, you can have 2 different result, which is what I wanted.
is there a fix, or alternative from `fscanf()`, since it can't read 2 string?

Comment: Also. do never us `*scanf("%s")`, better use `fgets()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably, your scanning is failing.

*Moral of the story: Always check the return value of `scanf()` family for success before trying to use the scanned value.*

In your case,

```
  fscanf(test, "%s\n", custid[i].name);
```

needs an explicit `'\n'` to be present in the input to be match, without that, the matching will fail.

Probably you want to remove the `'\n'` from the format string in the scanning part.

After that, as mentioned in the [other answer by W.Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43994889/2173917), the positioning of `rewind()` appears wrong, too. You need to rewind once, before the reading starts. Make the call outside the reading loop.

Comment: After removing `\n` from `fscanf(test, "%s\n", custid[i].name);`. The result still remain, is there another alternative from `fscanf()`

Comment: Yes. `getline()` is way better to iterate line by line through a file.

Comment: "needs an explicit '\n' to be present in the input to be match, without that, the matching will fail." --> No. The `'\n'` in the format will not fail `fscanf()`.  It matches 0 or more white-spaces from `test`.  It is not needed here, but it does not cause a failure.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is occurring because you put `rewind()` inside the for loop . Place it before the for loop. Then it will work fine.

```
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    fprintf(test, "%s\n", custid[i].name);
 }
 rewind(test);
 for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   // rewind(test); 
    fscanf(test, "%s\n", custid[i].name);
    printf("%s\n", custid[i].name);
 }
```